# Angular2 - Check IndexedDB usage

Tags: angular, indexeddb

I need to check indexedDb usage in order to know how many free space I can use.

I have to check this in an Angular2-4 application.

How to do this?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this.

```
// ##### START BOILERPLATE ######
var db;
var databaseName = 'database';
var objectStoreName = 'store1';
var req = indexedDB.open(databaseName);
req.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  db = req.result;
  db.createObjectStore(objectStoreName);
};
req.onsuccess = function() {
  db = req.result;
  main();
}
// ##### END BOILERPLATE ######

var control;
function main() {
  var txn = db.transaction([objectStoreName], 'readonly'];
  control = txn.observe(observerFunction);
  txn.oncomplete = function() {
    console.log('Observing is starting!');
  }
}

function observerFunction(changes) {
  console.log('Observer received changes!');
  // An object store that we're observing has changed.
  changes.records.forEach(function(records, objectStoreName) {
    console.log('Got changes for object store: ', objectStoreName);
    records.forEach(function(change) {
      // do something with change.type and change.key
      var type = change.type;
      switch (type) {
        case 'clear':
          console.log('object store cleared.');
          break;
        case 'add':
          console.log('key "', change.key, '" added.');
          break;
        case 'put':
          console.log('key "', change.key, '" putted.');
          break;
        case 'delete':
          console.log('key or range "', change.key, '" deleted.');
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kunvar, but where is the piece of code where you print the db size ?